# Apache Commons Lang StringUtils Slower

Tags: java, apache

> Background

Trying a simple experiment to find out if tradition `if` statement to check null is faster than Apache Commons Lang StringUtils `isEmpty`/`isBlank`.

To run this test, I am using `Java 8u102`, Apache Commons Lang version `3.4` and running on Windows 10 64-bit.

> The Test Code

Below are the test codes using standard main class:

```
        System.out.println("Testing of StringUtils.isNotNull vs native java method");
        System.out.println("======================================================");
        System.out.println("Testing conventional method...");
        final List<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();
        array.add("1");
        array.add(null);
        array.add("3");
        array.add(null);
        array.add("5");
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (String s : array) {
            System.out.println(s == null ? "yes" : "no");
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
        System.out.println("Testing StringUtils method...");
        start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (String s : array) {
            System.out.println(StringUtils.isBlank(s) ? "yes" : "no");
        }
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - start);
```

> The Result

```
Testing of StringUtils.isNotNull vs native java method
======================================================
Testing conventional method...
no
yes
no
yes
no
0
Testing StringUtils method...
no
yes
no
yes
no
6
```

To my very surprised that native method is way faster than Apache Commons Lang library.

> The Question

Can anyone pointed out if my result is conclusive? Is there any chances that my test is wrong therefore such result? Thanks.

Comment: Well, [look at the source](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html). Seems like it would take longer

Comment: I guess the overhead is for double/triple check use.

Comment: Your code is using StringUtils#isBlank which is doing more than just null testing, it checks for empty "" string and only whitespaces string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: I highly recommend you look at JMH http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/ for microbenchamrks in Java.

---

When you load a class, it takes time and in the String example, this class is already loaded.

When writing a benchmark you need to

- let the code warmup up for at least 2 - 30 seconds (depending on the complexity of the code)
- run the test for at least 5 to 30 seconds.
- remove any printing. Writing to the console is often 10,000x slower than most basic operations.

Any test which is a few milli-seconds long is likely to be time something like the time to load the class.

> Is there any chances that my test is wrong therefore such result?

The operations you are testing should be tens of nano-seconds. A result of 6 milli-seconds is likely to be out by about 100,000x.

Comment: thanks for the valuable feedback, i edited the code above to include one time warm up for StringUtils and the result shows faster than traditional if check statement.

Comment: @d4v1dv00 try repeating the test for at least 2 seconds, and dividing by the number of times. e.g. try at least 100,000 times and repeat this test 5+ times to see if it is still speeding up.  Note: iteration takes some time.

Comment: thanks for the advice. i will do the actual run offline.